# ListView with an extra argument

Tags: django, django-views, django-listview

I want to add a parameter `somevar` to my listview:

```
{% url 'products' somevar %}?"
```

in the urls:

```
path("products/<int:somevar>", ProductListView.as_view(), name = 'products'),
```

in the views:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        print(self.kwargs) # {"somevar": xxxxx}
        return f"{TEMPLATE_ROOT}/products.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.get_products().order_by("number")
        print(kwargs) # kwargs is {} here
        return context
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().order_by("number")
```

How can I pass the variable to the `get_context_data` method? I tried defining a `get` method and call `self.get_context_data(**kwargs)` within, but this leads to an `object has no attribute 'object_list'` error.

Comment: print(self.kwargs), class ListView has different kwargs then get_context_data method

Comment: haha ... yes. It was that simple. Please can you post this as an answer? I want to accept it.

Comment: Hello @xtlc *``object has no attribute 'object_list'``*  for this you can try this ``self.object_list = self.get_queryset()`` inside your ``get()`` method I know you've got solution but I'm giving you one more way so next time maybe this will help you(;

Comment: Basically you mean I need to move `self.get_products()` from `get_context_data()` to `get()`?

Comment: Ankit is saying you need to set `self.object_list` in your `get()` method, or you can `return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)` which automatically sets `self.object_list` for you after your custom code in the `get()` method

Comment: Class Based Views can be tricky when you are first learning them, these docs can be helpful https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `View` class has different `kwargs` than the `get_context_data` method

The `kwargs` of a `View` contain the URL Parameters

The `kwargs` passed to the `get_context_data` method are passed to the template for rendering

Since you want to access a URL Parameter in `get_context_data` you would use `self.kwargs` (`self` is referring to your `View` class)